# Dynamic page creation using files from a particular directory

Tags: next.js

I have a component that is the default layout for all pages in my application. I want this component to read a particular directory and link existing files within the component. To be very clear, I am generating pages dynamically with the files available in the directory.

Now the problem is, this component of mine is not inside of `/pages` folder and using `getStaticProps` outside this directory is restricted.

```
import { getSortedPageData } from '../lib/pages'


export async function getStaticProps() {
    const allPagesData = getSortedPageData()
    return {
        props: {
            allPagesData
        }
    }
}

export default function Layout({ allPagesData }) {
return(
    <Navbar color="faded" light>
    <Collapse isOpen={!collapsed} navbar>
        <Nav navbar>
            {allPagesData.map(({ page, title }) => (
                <NavItem key={page}>
                    <Link href="/[page]" as={page}>
                        <a>
                            <NavLink>{title}</NavLink>
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                </NavItem>
            ))}
        </Nav>
    </Collapse>
    </Navbar>
)}
```

So, I can't actually do this what I wrote above. What should I do on this situation?

The problem only arise when I am creating Links like above in the component, because it is outside the `/pages` dir. I have no issue generating dynamic pages for the files.

Please advise,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getStaticProps` used to fetch data at **build time**.

You can extend the build process by writing a custom Node.js script that will go through the files and create a `.json` file with the menu information.

The created `.json` file can be imported in the `Layout` component on a client-side.

You would need to extend npm script `build` in the `package.json`, so `next build` and your script would run with one command.

Comment: Thanks. I generated a `.json` file with the pages yaml data and imported here in this component. All I needed just to do this, because page generation works anyway as it is done from the `/pages` dir.